# Single updates using tf.GradientTape with multiple outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I defined the following model, which has two distinct outputs:

```
input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape = (1, 20), name = "input_features")

# Shared layers
hidden_1 = keras.layers.Dense(32, 
                            activation = "relu", 
                            name = "LSTM_shared_l"
                            )(input_layer)

# Additional layers
hidden_2 = keras.layers.Dense(32, 
                              activation = "selu",
                              name = "Forecasting_extra_layer_1"
                              )(input_layer)

hidden_3 = keras.layers.Dense(32, 
                              activation = "selu",
                              name = "Forecasting_extra_layer_2"
                              )(hidden_2)


# Output layers
f_output = keras.layers.Dense(1, 
                              name = "F_output")(hidden_1)

rl_output = keras.layers.Dense(32, 
                               name = "RL_output")(hidden_3)

model = keras.Model(inputs = [input_layer], outputs = [f_output, rl_output])


model.summary()
```

and I would like to train it with GradientTape, performing single iterations; with only one output, I would use the following code:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        
        predictions = model(inputs)
        pred_values = tf.reduce_sum(predictions, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss_fn(target_pred, pred_values))
    
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

How can I extend it to the multiple outputs scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple strategies, the simplest one is to calculate the loss from both outputs and sum the results together:

```
predictions_1, predictions_2 = model(inputs)

predictions_1 = ...
predictions_2 = ... # any desired post-processing 

loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss_fn(target_1, predictions_1)) + tf.reduce_mean(loss_fn(target_2, predictions_2))
```

and then you can safely descend:

```
grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```